# can we apply KQL function on the KQL table data?

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have a KQL table with one newly added column(empty values), i want to insert values into that column with previous values of another column.
I am not able to apply previous logic on the entire table as we have huge data and we are getting memory allocation error for the query.
Can anyone help how can i apply function on each row, so that it wont take entire data for the calculation.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried with?

Comment: Country
|where State == "US"
| summarize arg_max(EventTime,*) by FullProductName
Above is an simple query where i am unable to run it because its giving me an arithmetic overflow error because of huge data i have. So its not able to apply sort or any order by operations in the table . So i wanted to create a function with a logic to take previous value and wanted to apply on the table. OS that for each row it has to take that row's data and do the logic.

Comment: Could you please update the question with what you have tried and what kind of errors you are facing with? and also what is your expected output. It is tough to understand by comments.